# Retrieve Item from selected row in a Datgrid using databinding

Tags: c#, winforms, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a list bound to a `Datagrid` via a `Bindinglist`, I need a full 2 way databinding

```
 MyBindingList = new BindingList<Item>(List<Item>);
 SmartGridItems.DataSource = _myBindingList;
```

I cannot find out now, how I can access the `Item`, if I know the row in the grid.

e.g. after editing I want to validate the item, but I can do that only if I get a reference to the Item that has been edited.

Or how can I retrieve the item in my list if I know the associated row in the grid.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `DataBoundItem` of the `DataGridViewRow`:

```
var item = (Item) row.DataBoundItem;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. Unfortunately the Row of the Grid I use does not have a propberty DataBoundItem (), but I just checked it. It seems the same property in my Grid is called Data, so thank you very much. Probably this is the answer.

Comment: @Wolfgang are you using a third-part `grid`? I thought you're using the standard `DataGridView`.

Comment: @Wolfgang looks like you're using the obsolete control `DataGrid` in `winforms`, you should use a `DataGridView` instead, it's more functional and productive. Even using the standard `DataGridView` is not good (for its appearance) but at least it's the standard control.

Comment: Actually I am using a third party grid, that also runs on Windows Embedded Compact 7 Resco Smartgrid, but I did not mention it, because I was greatful for any hint, and with your hint, it really think I solved my problem. Thank you.